# Unhandled rejection Error: Couldn't decode uint256 from ABI

Tags: solidity, web3js, testrpc, nodejs, solc

I am working on using a sample Contract using NodeJS, Web3, and Solc but I encountered some error that the given address in the Contract that I've created couldn't decode. Am I doing something wrong? Here is the JS code that I'm working on

```
const Web3  = require('web3');
const fs    = require('fs');
const solc  = require('solc');

let web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

const source = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/solidity/Token.sol');
const output = solc.compile(source.toString(), 1);
const bytecode = output.contracts[':Token'].bytecode;
const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':Token'].interface);

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x5bbf74f1e804bfe671d55cd6b9f3ada66568d5dd', {
  from: web3.eth.coinbase,
  gasPrice: 90000*2
});

contract.methods.totalSupply().call().then(function (err, result) {
  console.log('error', err);
  console.log('result', result);
});
```

Here is the solidity code that I am using.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {
    // stores the balances of the addresses
    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) approved;

    // number of tokens in circulation
    uint supply;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    function Token() {
        // constructor
        // balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint) {
        return supply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value
            && _value > 0
        ) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;

            // trigger an event
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // sets how many can a spender spend from a certain address
    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] > _value) {
            approved[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // check the value of the spender can spend
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining) {
        return approved[_owner][_spender];
    }

    // transfer the approved value to spend
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) constant returns (bool success) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value
            && approved[_from][msg.sender] >= _value
            && _value > 0
        ) {
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            approved[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;


            balances[_to] += _value;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

PS: I'm using `testrpc` as my ethereum provider.

Comment: i'm also facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: @comeback4you no, what i did is i downgraded my webjs from 1.0.0 beta 20-ish version to 0.20 then it worked fine.

Comment: @RicoMaglayon Have you found solution of this problem, without downgrading `web3js` lib?

Comment: hey @DmytroZarezenko i never looked back once i downgraded `web3js` library. sorry about that.

Comment: for me the solution was   upgrading web3js to  ^1.0.0-beta.22. npm update --save web3 or npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.22

Comment: Did anyone get any solution? I'm still facing same issue after update.

Comment: @comeback4you have you tried the solution of Badr Bellaj? using 1.0.0-beta.22 version?

Comment: Yes, same issue. https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1089

Comment: tried to use this functionality again using 1.0.0-beta.24 and instead compiling the solidity code on-the-fly, i compiled it using [remix.ethereum.org](http://remix.ethereum.org), fetched the bytecode and the abi saved it on a JSON file and it works fine.

Comment: here is a gist for what i did: [https://gist.github.com/ricomonster/88baecd59858690a1d79d5ab8a6e0c72](https://gist.github.com/ricomonster/88baecd59858690a1d79d5ab8a6e0c72)

Comment: @RicoMaglayon Since this seems like a fairly common issue, do you mind posting an answer to your own question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

I was totally stuck on this issue myself until I realized I had metamask set to the wrong network (mainnet instead of rinkeby). It's worth checking that setting... I definitely felt silly once I realized after blowing quite a bit of time trying to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the solution of your problem because of your comment about the `web3` version.

You are compiling a new version of your smart contract with `solc` but you never deploying it and updating the contract address, that can be the issue if you have an outdated ABI